# In RSpec, Is there a way to get information about the example to be tested for use in before(:each)?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I would like to keep track at runtime of the RSpec test currently being executed, preferably including its file name and line number, so that if a test hangs I can know where to find it. I'm thinking of simply writing the file name and line number to a file in a `before(:each)`.

I realize I can see in the output the *most recently* executed test, but I would like to know the *currently executing* test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`before(:each)` yields [an `RSpec::Core::Example` instance](https://rspec.info/documentation/3.11/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Example.html) representing the current test/example, which should contain the information you're after.

```
before(:each) do |example|
  puts example.description
  puts example.location
  puts example.metadata
end
```